# Method does not return a new instance of a UILabel

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

Method declaration,

```
-(UILabel *)returnUILabel:(UILabel *)myLabel color:(UIColor *)labelColor x:(int)xParameter     y:(int)yParamater width:(int)widthParameter height:(int)heightParameter
{
    CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(xParameter, yParamater, widthParameter, heightParameter);
    myLabel = [myLabel initWithFrame:cellFrame];
    myLabel.text = @"Testing";
    myLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1,1);
    myLabel.backgroundColor = labelColor;
    return myLabel;
}
```

called as below in viewDidLoad ,

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
UIColor *labelColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self.view addSubview:[self returnUILabel:myLabel color:labelColor x:17 y:260 width:140 height:130]];
labelColor = [UIColor yellowColor] ;
[self.view addSubview:[self returnUILabel:myLabel color:labelColor x:170 y:260 width:140 height:130]];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

On my view i only see yellow color labels whereas i should see one red and one yellow. why ??.
The same approach works fine on a `UIImageView`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one `UILabel`, all you did was modifying that label, not creating a new instance of the label

```
- (UILabel *)returnUILabelWithColor:(UIColor *)labelColor x:(int)xParameter y:(int)yParamater width:(int)widthParameter height:(int)heightParameter
{
    CGRect cellFrame = CGRectMake(xParameter, yParamater, widthParameter, heightParameter);
    UILabel* newLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cellFrame] autorelease];
    newLabel.text = @"Testing";
    newLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1,1);
    newLabel.backgroundColor = labelColor;
    return newLabel;
}
```

Comment: You could also remove `myLabel` from the method arguments for clarity's sake.

Comment: Good catch! I just copied the method from above. Thanks

Comment: Yes i know i have one label and thats all i need. The parameters passed are different in each case so currently i can see two labels added in different vectors on the screen. If what you are saying is correct why is this approach working on a UIIMageView ? and why am i downvoted ??

Comment: @XSlash your method works and is cleaner though i still have to get why the previous approach works on a UIIMageview. Thanks.

Comment: I can't answer for sure because I can't see how you do it with your UIImageView. However, I suggest you change it, even if it might work now, it's not a good way to do it. If you're not using ARC, you're leaking memory. I don't know why you're downvoted

Comment: I did change the UIMageView code as well. Code is more understandable now and i am using ARC. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the fact that you have only got *one* `UILabel` object and that you are adding it as a subview twice. This will not make a copy of the label.

From [UIView reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/addSubview%3a):

> Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous superview before making the receiver its new superview.

as a corollary, if the superview is the same, adding a subview that has been already added will simply put it on top of all other views.

Comment: But on the second go i am sending the label with a different color so i should get a label with the red and yellow. Like i said the approach works fine on a UIImageView. Thanks

Comment: Try this: `[self.view addSubview:[self returnUILabel:[myLabel copy] color:labelColor x:170 y:260 width:140 height:130]];`. You definitely need a second object if you want to have two object on the screen. There is no other way, sorry.